# Youtube-dl vs Streamlink vs livestreamer vs FFmpeg В чём разница?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, streaming, youtube-dl

Прошу сразу не дизлайкать этот вопрос. На самом деле он достаточно часто встречался мне, но без ответа.
Поставил себе задачу: взять видеопоток(youtube/twitch/любой другой источник) и записывать его локально, после чего проводить махинации с видео (обрезать,отправлять и т.п.) Столкнулся с трудностью выбора софта. Я выделил 4 реализации процесса записи стримов.

1. **Youtube-dl**
2. **Streamlink**
3. **livestreamer**
4. **FFmpeg**

Кто-то даже делал через парсеры html (bs и подобные). Я долго разбирался, какая мне нужна реализация, но так и не понял, что лучше подойдёт. Так же, меня смутило, что кто-то использует сразу несколько библиотек одновременно. Т.е. я видел реализации FFmpeg + Streamlink/FFmepg + Youtube-dl.

Так как в этой сфере я не специалист я бы хотел услышать мнения более опытных в этом людей.
Буду крайне рад грамотному разъяснению!

Comment: youtube-dl и streamlink и так используют парсер+ffmpeg внутри себя

Comment: А что бы посоветовали, в основном я разрываюсь между youtube-dl и streamlink, т.к. streamlink, если не ошибаюсь форк livestreamer

Comment: А почему разрываетесь? Попробуйте один из, если делает, что вам нужно, то второй можно и не смотреть. А ответить на это вопрос объективно нельзя. Основные функции, вероятно есть везде, а сложность заключается в `и т.п.`